# Why are these two expressions representing eigendecomposition equivalent?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am familiar with the expression for the eigendecomposition of a matrix
$$
A = Q\Lambda Q^{-1}
$$
where $Q$ is a matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors of $A$ and $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with the $i^{\text{th}}$ diagonal element being the eigenvalue corresponding to the eigenvector in the $i^{\text{th}}$ column of $Q$.

I have also seen the eigendecomposition expressed this way:
$$
A = \sum\limits_{i}\lambda_i\mathbf{x_i}\mathbf{x_i}^T
$$
where each vector $\mathbf{x_i}$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$ eigenvector. However, I am having some difficulty visualizing why this summation is equivalent to the matrix multiplication expression above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only a correspondence when $Q$ is orthogonal, i.e. $Q^{-1} = Q^\top$. (This is possible if $A$ is symmetric.)

Then with $x_i$ being the $i$th column of $Q$, the two expressions are equal. I think if you write $\Lambda$ as the sum of $n$ matrices, each diagonal with one nonzero entry $\lambda_i$ in the $i$th diagonal entry, then you can see the correspondence.

Comment: "if you write Λ as the sum of n matrices, each diagonal with one nonzero entry λi in the ith diagonal entry, then you can see the correspondence."

Perfect! This was exactly what I needed to help visualize it.